# Determinant of a Linear Transformation is Unique Up to a Unit

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Can anyone explain the following assertion from a textbook I'm reading?

"...$R$ is a Dedekind domain, $K$ its quotient field, $U$ a finite dimensional vector space over $K$ of dimension $n > 0$ ... $M, N$ stand for finitely generated $R$-submodules which span $U$, i.e. contain a basis of $U$...Now suppose for the moment that $M$ and $N$ are free $R$-modules.  They are both of rank $n$, hence isomorphic.  Therefore there is a non-singular linear transformation $l$ of $U$ with $l(M) = N$.  The determinant $Det(l)$ is non-zero and, apart from a unit in $R$, solely depends on $M$ and $N$.  Hence the fractional ideal $$R Det(l) = [M : N] $$ solely depends on $M$ and $N$."

I see how $M$ and $N$ both have rank $n$, but I don't understand how the determinants $Det(l)$ are associates in $R$ for various $K$-isomorphisms $l: U \rightarrow U$ satisfying $l(M) = N$.

Edit: I misunderstood the context, so I've rewritten the problem word for word to avoid any future confusion.  This is from Frohlich's section on local fields in the book "Algebraic Number Theory."

Comment: Where are you reading this?  I think this is quite a weird thing to write...  $Det(l)$ is a unit because $1 = Det(l \circ l^{-1}) = Det(l)Det(l^{-1})$.  Not sure what more the author could be trying to say here though...

Comment: "Linear transformation $\;l\;$ of $\;U\;$ ..."   to **where** ?? And what's the relation between that vector space and those free $\;R-$ modules ?

Comment: @user114722 What does $RDet(l)$ and $[M:N]$ mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two isomorphisms $l_1,l_2:M\to N$ then $l_1^{-1}\circ l_2$ is an automorphism of the module $M$. Thus its determinant has to be a unit. As automorphisms of $U$, the determinants $l_1$ and $l_2$ differ then exactly by this unit.

Comment: If $v_1, ... , v_n \in M$ is a basis for $U$, then the fact that $M$ is free (over $A$) means that $v_1, ... , v_n$ is linearly independent over $M$ and therefore a basis.  For another basis $w_1, ... , w_n \in M$, why can't we define an $A$-module isomorphism by $v_i \mapsto w_i$?  Wouldn't that mean the determinant would be $1$?

Comment: No, the determinant would be that of the matrix of the coefficients expressing the $w$ basis in the $v$ basis, $w_i=\sum_j a_{ij}v_i$. Since that matrix has to be invertible, the determinant is invertible too and thus a unit.